# jQuery playlist function error: function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to create a **.mp3** player to just loop through audio tracks, but I keep getting error on Firebug that the main function I use is undefined, although I do define it. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var counter=1;
var nextSong = function(){
    if (counter <= 3) {
        $('audio').src="audio/audio"+counter+".ogg";
        $this.load();
        $this.play();
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        counter=0;
        $('audio').src="audio/audio"+counter+".ogg";
        $this.load();
        $this.play();
    };
  };
});
```

And my markup is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Dokimastiko Audio Player</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dokimastiko.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio src="audio/audio1.ogg" controls autoplay onended="nextSong();"></audio>
    </body>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the function it says is undefined?

Comment: No idea what `$this` is. It's not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: setting the `src` property of a jQuery object is useless. Use `.prop` to set the property of the underlying DOM elements.

Comment: `$(this)` should refer to the audio element, won't it?

Comment: @litzel `$this` is just a variable name. Although it's normally set to `$(this)`, you don't set it anywhere. `$(this)` wraps the function context in a jQuery object. The context depends on how it's called.

Comment: tried the .prop("src", "path/to/audio") but didn't change anything. nextSong() still undefined.

Comment: If you attach `nextSong` through jQuery by `.on("onended", nextSong)`, `this` will refer to the `audio`. `onended = "nextSong()"` will not set the context (`this === window` in non-strict code, `this === undefined` in strict code)

Comment: @litzel oh. It's only defined inside the `ready` block, but you're trying to use it outside. Remove the `onended` attribute and attach the function via `$("audio").on("ended", nextSong)`

Comment: @JanDvorak if I get it right, I changed `$(this)` into `$('audio')`, still didn't work.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what you ment on the last 2 comments. Newbie here.

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question. It invalidates existing answers

Answer (score 2):

I debated on whether to give you a full lesson on why your code is pretty bad... And since I have little on my plate at work right now I'll do so... :P

First of all the `$this` you have there is undefined, so obviously calling a method on it is going to be undefined as well.

You probably copied the code from somewhere, which is fine, but you need to be able to copy is smartly instead of blindly.

.... you changed your code midway of my post, so update:
`$(this)` is the same as `$(document)` since that is the context of `this` within `$(document).ready(function() {})`

So, nope, still wrong.

So the first modification, it should be:

```
$('audio').load();
$('audio').play();
```

But actually that is still wrong. Because `$('audio')` is a jquery object, and it does not contain the DOM-level methods `load` and `play` directly, so you need to get the DOM object:

```
$('audio').get(0).load();
$('audio').get(0).play();
```

Now you would be wondering why the `.get(0)`, it's because `$('audio')` is a *collection* of all the matches to `'audio'`, so `get(0)` would return the first one only.

This is prone to breakage if you decide to add more `audio` tags to the page, so you should give the audio tag a unique identifier:

```
<audio src="audio/audio1.ogg" controls autoplay onended="nextSong();" id="audio1"></audio>
```

And then use the id in your jquery selector:

```
$('#audio1').get(0).load();
$('#audio1').get(0).play();
```

This is still abit verbose, but given that you only need to do this, this is the simplest way.

***UPDATE:***

As per suggested by @JanDvorak here is a example that uses jquery events as well

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MpBP5/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#audio1').bind('ended', function(e) {
        alert('end');
    });
});
```

I can also keep going on this "lesson", you should try not to define your music urls that abstractly, what if someone just leaves your page on and it hits a file which, for that counter #, doesn't exist?

I would declare an array of files you wish to load:

```
var library = [
    'http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3',
    'http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3',
    'http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3',
    'http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip'
];
var currentIndex = 0;
```

Then loop through the list:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#audio1').bind('ended', function(e) {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex > library.length-1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        this.src = library[currentIndex];
        $('#url').html(library[currentIndex]);
    });

    $('#audio1').attr('src', library[currentIndex]);
        $('#url').html(library[currentIndex]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MpBP5/3/

If you don't want a fixed list of audio files to play (which you really should), you can generate the array with at least some rules.

Comment: the context of `$(this)` in OP's code is not set by `ready`, but by the `nextSong` caller.

Comment: I prefer `$el[0]` over `$el.get(0)`

Comment: And, of course, `#audio1` is non-semantic and should be changed to a better ID by the asker ;-)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but didn't get it work, `nextSong()` still appears undefined... thanks for your detailed info, but the code was my idea, that's why so many mistakes actually... copy-paste usually doesn't result in so many mistakes;)

Comment: @JanDvorak yea you're right I missed that part, so `this.load()` would've worked.

Comment: @litzel sorry for the long delay and the mistakes... You need to put the function outside of the `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: @Populus better yet, attach the event handler inside `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Sorry for delay, was driving home from work, I took the `nextSong()` out of `$(document).ready()` and added an event listener to `$('#audio1')`, but now counter appears as undefined...

Comment: so take the counter out as well... but you can try to put an event listener within the document.ready block. Try taking the `counter` outside of `document.ready` first

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#audio1').get(0).addEventListener("ended", nextSong);
});` the rest of the javascript is outside `$(document).ready()`